why does it open with any pass after i use the correct password once?
I have 2 HTML files, one with just a form(which takes in a password) and one with secrets. I wrote this js code but when I run it, it refuses every wrong password until I put the correct password once and then when I go back it takes all the incorrect passwords as well.
Where am I going wrong?
import express from "express";
import { dirname } from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
import bodyParser from "body-parser";


const app = express();
var userAuthorised = false;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

function passCheck(req, res, next) {
    
    if (req.body["password"] === "ILoveProgramming"){
        userAuthorised = true;
    }
    next();
}

app.use(passCheck);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
});

app.post("/check", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    if(userAuthorised){
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/secret.html");
    }
    else {
        res.redirect("/");
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server Running on port 3000");
});


Because userAuthorised is a global variable. It doesn't apply to a request, it applies to every request, from every client.

This seems like a great time for you to start looking into existing authentication functionality instead of creating your own.

You should find a better way of handling authorization. Check out jwt

When you start the server, you initialize
var userAuthorised = false;

Once, it's set to
userAuthorised = true;

it's never set back to false, because it's a global variable and the initialization happens only once at the start.
The condition
if(userAuthorised){

will always be true after the first correct login.
The solution is to not use a global variable for this. A common pattern in Express is to store additional values in the request, e.g.
req.userAuthorised = true;

and check them with
if(req.userAuthorised){

